# Restrictions in Protégé

Tags: ontology, owl, protege, protege4

I'm following the Protégé tutorial and doing the steps of the Pizza ontology.

The problem is that I cannot create a restriction. I can't find the Superclasses header. How can I do it?

Comment: What Protégé version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Protégé 4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the SubClass Of section. It was renamed in Protégé 4.3.